# Unable to connect to Microsoft MySQL server using python code getting error

Tags: python, sql-server, robotframework

I'm unable to connect to Microsoft MySQL server using Python code. I'm getting error like below

**code**

```
import pyodbc

server = 'xxx'
database = 'xxx'
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xx'
driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=portnumber;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlCode.py", line 12, in <module>
    with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=2078;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (2)')
```

Comment: MySQL is a database engine offered by Oracle. It is not SQL Server which is the database engine offered by Microsoft. These are important distinctions to know. Note that you do not have any portnumber defined in your code, but you separate server name (or address) and port number with comma, not semicolon. Do you **know** that the port number is correct? Can you connect using SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Share my experience,
Maybe it's about `SSMS permission` problem.

You can go to **IP>Security>Login>Account>property** to confirm whether the account has the permission to connect to the database.

I have the same code as yours, until I do permission confirmation, it works to me.